# Any way to use filter-branch in a incremental sense

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

Is there any way to use filter-branch in a incremental manner on a branch?

roughly speaking like this (but this isn't actually working):

```
git checkout -b branchA origin/branchA  
git branch headBranchA  
# inital rewrite   
git filter-branch ... -- branchA  
git fetch origin  
# incremental rewrite  
git filter-branch ... -- headBranchA..origin/branchA  
git merge origin/branchA
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve, so what I will say here is "yes, sort of, but probably not what you're thinking and it might not help you achieve your goal, whatever that is".

It's important to understand here not just *what* `filter-branch` does, but also, to some extent, *how* it does it.

---

### Background (to make this answer useful to others)

A git repository contains some commit-graph(s).  These are found by taking some starting commit nodes, found via external references—mostly branch and tag names, but also annotated tags which I'll just sort of gloss over as not particularly important to this case—and then using those starting nodes to find more nodes, until all "reachable" nodes have been found.

Each commit has zero or more "parent commits".  Most ordinary commits have one parent; merges have two or more parents.  A root commit (such as the initial commit in a repository) has no parents.

Branch names point to one particular commit, which points back to its parent(s), and so on.

```
  B-C-D
 /     \
A---E---F   <-- master
 \
  G     J   <-- branch1
   \   /
    H-I-K   <-- branch2
```

Branch name `master` points to commit `F` (which is a merge commit).  The names `branch1` and `branch2` point to commits `J` and `K` respectively.

Let's also note that, because commits point to their parents, the "reachable set" from name `master` is `A B C D E F`, the set for `branch1` is `A G H I J`, and the set for `branch2` is `A G H I K`.

The "true name" of each commit node is its SHA-1, which is a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit.  The contents include SHA-1 checksums of the corresponding work-tree contents and the SHA-1s of the parent commits.  Thus, if you go to copy a commit and change *nothing* (not one single bit) you get the same SHA-1 back and hence wind up with the *same* commit; but if you change even a single bit (including, e.g., changing the spelling of the committer's name, any time stamps, or any part of the associated work-tree), you get a new, different commit.

#### `git rev-parse` and `git rev-list`

These two commands are quite central to most git operation.

The `rev-parse` command turns [any valid git revision specifier](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) into a commit-ID.  (It also has a lot of what we might call "assistance modes", that allow writing most git commands as shell scripts—and `git filter-branch` is in fact a shell script.)

The `rev-list` command turns a revision *range* (also in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)) into a list of commit-IDs.  Given *just* a branch name, it finds the set of *all* revisions reachable from that branch, so with the example commit graph above, given `branch2`, it lists the SHA-1 values for commits `A`, `G`, `H`, `I`, and `K`.  (It defaults to listing them in reverse chronological order, but can be told to list them in "topographic order", which is important to `filter-branch`, not that I intend to get that deep into the details here.)

In this case, though, you will want to use "commit limiting": given a revision *range*, like the `A..B` syntax, or given things like `B ^A`, `git rev-list` limits its output rev-sets to commits that are reachable from `B`, but *not* reachable from `A`.  Hence, given `branch2~3..branch2`—or euivalently, `branch2 ^branch2~3`—it lists the SHA-1 values for `H`, `I`, and `K`.  This is because `branch2~3` names commit `G`, so commits `A` and `G` are pruned away from the reachable set.

---

#### `git filter-branch`

The filter-branch script is fairly complex but summarizing its action on "ref names given on the command line" is not too hard.

First, it uses `git rev-parse` to find the actual head revisions of the branch or branches to be filtered.  It uses it twice, in fact: once to get SHA-1 values, and once to get names.  Given, e.g., `headBranchA..origin/branchA`, it needs to get the "true full name" `refs/remotes/origin/branchA`:

```
git rev-parse --revs-only --symbolic-full-name headBranchA..origin/branchA
```

will print:

```
refs/remotes/origin/branchA
^refs/heads/headBranchA
```

The filter-branch script discards any `^`-prefixed results to get a list of "positive ref names"; these are what it intends to rewrite, in the end.

**These are the "positive refs" described in the [git-filter-branch manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html).**

Then it uses `git rev-list` to get a complete list of commit SHA-1s on which to apply the filters.  This is where the `headBranchA..origin/branchA` limiting syntax comes in: the script now knows to work only on commits reachable from `origin/branchA`, but not from `headBranchA`.

Once it has the list of commit IDs, `git filter-branch` actually applies the filters.  These make new commits.

As always, if the new commits are exactly identical to the original commits, the commit-IDs are unchanged.  If filter-branch is to be useful, though, presumably at some point, some commits are changed, giving them new SHA-1s.  Any immediate children of those commits have to acquire new parent IDs, so those commits are also changed, and those changes propagate down to the ultimate branch-tips.

Finally, having applied the filters to all the listed commits, the `filter-branch` script updates the "positive refs".

---

The next part depends on your actual filters.  Let's just assume for illustration that your filter changes the spelling of an author name on every commit, or changes the time-stamp on every commit, or some such, so that every commit is rewritten, except for some reason it leaves the root commit unchanged, so that the new branch and the old one do have a common ancestor.

We start with this:

```
git checkout -b branchA origin/branchA
```

(you are now on `branchA`, i.e., `HEAD` contains `ref: refs/heads/branchA`)

```
git branch headBranchA
```

(this makes another branch label pointing to the current `HEAD` commit but does not alter `HEAD`)

```
# inital rewrite
git filter-branch ... -- branchA
```

The "positive ref" in this case is `branchA`.  The commits to be rewritten are every commit reachable from `branchA`, i.e., all the `o` nodes below (starting commit graph made up for illustration here), except for the root commit `R`:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x   <-- master
     \
      o-o-o   <-- headBranchA, HEAD=branchA, origin/branchA
```

Every `o` commit is copied, and `branchA` is moved to point to the last new one:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x   <-- master
|    \
|     o-o-o   <-- headBranchA, origin/branchA
 \
  *-*-*-*-*   <-- HEAD=branchA
```

Later, you go to pick up new stuff from remote `origin`:

```
git fetch origin
```

Let's say this adds commits labeled `n` (and I'll just add one):

```
R-o-o-x-x-x   <-- master
|    \
|     o-o-o   <-- headBranchA
|          \
|           n <-- origin/branchA
 \
  *-*-*-*-*   <-- HEAD=branchA
```

Here's where things go wrong:

```
git filter-branch ... -- headBranchA..origin/branchA
```

The "positive ref" here is `origin/branchA`, so *that's what will be moved*.  The commits selected by the [rev-list](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) are just those marked `n`, which is what you want.  Let's spell the rewritten commit `N` (uppercase) this time:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x   <-- master
|    \
|     o-o-o   <-- headBranchA
|         |\
|         | n [semi-abandoned - filter-branch writes refs/original/...]
|          \
|           N <-- origin/branchA
 \
  *-*-*-*-*   <-- HEAD=branchA
```

And now you attempt to `git merge origin/branchA`, which means to `git merge` commit `N`, which requires finding the merge base between the `*` chain and commit `N` ... and that's commit `R`.

This is not, I assume, what you meant to do at all.

I suspect what you want to do is, instead, cherry-pick commit `N` onto the `*` chain.  Let's draw that in:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x   <-- master
|    \
|     o-o-o   <-- headBranchA
|         |\
|         | n [semi-abandoned - filter-branch writes refs/original/...]
|          \
|           N <-- origin/branchA
 \
  *-*-*-*-*-N'<-- HEAD=branchA
```

This part is OK, but it's left a mess for the future.  It turns out you don't actually want commit `N` at all, and you don't want to move `origin/branchA`, because (I assume) you'd like to be able to repeat the `git fetch origin` step later.  So let's "undo" this and try something different.  Let's drop the `headBranchA` label entirely and start with this:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x   <-- master
|    \
|     o-o-o   <-- origin/branchA
 \
  *-*-*-*-*   <-- HEAD=branchA
```

Let's add a temporary marker for the commit to which `origin/branchA` points, and run `git fetch origin`, so that we get commit `n`:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x     <-- master
|    \     .--------temp
|     o-o-o-n   <-- origin/branchA
 \
  *-*-*-*-*     <-- HEAD=branchA
```

Now let's copy commit `n` to `branchA`, and while we're copying it, modify it too (doing whatever mods you would do with `git filter-branch`) to get a commit we'll just call `N`:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x     <-- master
|    \     .--------temp
|     o-o-o-n   <-- origin/branchA
 \
  *-*-*-*-*-N    <-- HEAD=branchA
```

When this is done we erase `temp` and we're ready to repeat the cycle.

---

### Making it work

That leaves several problems.  The most obvious is: how do we copy `n` (or several/many `n`s) and then modify them?  Well, the easy way, assuming you have your `filter-branch` already working, is to use `git cherry-pick` to copy them, then `git filter-branch` to filter them.

This only works if the `cherry-pick` step is not going to run into tree-difference issues, so it depends on what your filter does:

```
# all of this to be done while on branchA
git tag temp origin/branchA
git fetch origin # pick up `n` commit(s)

git tag temp2    # mark the point for filtering
git cherry-pick temp..origin/branchA
git filter-branch ... -- temp2..branchA

# remove temporary markers
git tag -d temp temp2
```

What if your filter-branch alters the tree, so that this method won't always work?  Well, we can resort to applying the filter directly to the `n` commits, giving `n'` commits, then copy the `n'` commits.  Those (`n''`) commits are the ones that will live on the local (filtered) `branchA`.  The `n'` commits are not needed once they've been copied, so we discard them.

```
# lay down temporary marker as before, and fetch
git tag temp origin/branchA
git fetch origin

# now make a new branch, just for filtering
git checkout -b temp2 origin/branchA
git filter-branch ... -- temp..temp2
# the now-altered new branch, temp..temp2, has filtered commits n'

# copy n' commits to n'' commits on branchA
git checkout branchA
git cherry-pick temp..temp2

# and finally, delete the temporary marker and the temporary branch
git tag -d temp
git branch -D temp2 # temp2 requires a force-delete
```

#### Other problems

We've covered (in the graph drawings) how *new* commits get copied-and-modified into your "incrementally filtered" `branchA`.  But what happens if, when you go consult `origin`, you find that commits were *removed*?

That is, we start with this:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x   <-- master
|    \
|     o-o-o   <-- origin/branchA
 \
  *-*-*-*-*   <-- HEAD=branchA
```

We lay down our temporary marker as usual and do `git fetch origin`.  But what they did was remove the last `o` commit, with a force-push on their end.  Now we have:

```
R-o-o-x-x-x   <-- master
|    \
|     o-o     <-- origin/branchA
|        `o.......temp
 \
  *-*-*-*-*   <-- HEAD=branchA
```

The implication here is that we probably should back `branchA` up one revision as well.

Whether you want to handle this at all is up to you.  I'll note here that the result of `git rev-list temp..origin/branchA` will be empty in this particular case (there are no commits on the revised `origin/branchA` that are not reachable from `temp`), but `origin/branchA..temp` will *not* be empty: it will list the one "removed" commit.  If two commits were removed, it would list the two commits, and so on.

It's possible for whoever controls `origin` to have removed several commits *and* added some other new commits (in fact, this is exactly what happens with an "upstream rebase").  In this case, both `git rev-list` commands will be non-empty: `origin/branchA..temp` will show you what was removed, and `temp..origin/branchA` will show you what was added.

Last, it's possible for whoever controls `origin` to completely wreck everything for you.  They can:

- remove their `branchA` entirely, or
- make their label `branchA` point to an *unrelated* branch.

Again, it's up to you whether, and if so how, to handle these cases.

Comment: Thank you for this eloborate explanation. This is very helpful!

Comment: How to handle merges?
Example:
Step 1) A and E exist and are filtered to A' and E'.
Step 2) B, C, D and F are added and need to be filtered.

Comment: @RenéScheibe: It's always a matter of selecting the commits to be copied and then applying your filters. If you select too few commits, you never get a chance to copy them. If you select too many, you must arrange for some of the new copies to be bit-for-bit identical to the originals (by designing your filters that way). At the end, the positive references you gave on the command line will be rewritten according to the map that `filter-branch` built.

Comment: "`git rev-list A..B` limits its output rev-sets to commits that are reachable from A, but not reachable from B". Shouldn't be the inverse (reachable from B, but not from A)?

Comment: @FernandoBertoldi: er, yes. A..B = B ^A. It's too easy to get this backwards... (fixed now, thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) does propose an incremental filtering now.

"`git filter-branch`" learned to use a different exit code to allow
the callers to tell the case where there was no new commits to
rewrite from other error cases.

See [commit 0a0eb2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a0eb2e585788567094248652fc20450a0db642b) (15 Mar 2018) by [Michele Locati (`mlocati`)](https://github.com/mlocati).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cb3e97d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb3e97dae806d66ea1859c48b9936d5bfbac9c09), 09 Apr 2018)</sup>

> ### filter-branch: return 2 when nothing to rewrite
>
> **Using the `--state-branch` option allows us to perform incremental filtering**.
> This may lead to having nothing to rewrite in subsequent filtering, so we need
> a way to recognize this case.
> So, let's exit with 2 instead of 1 when this "error" occurs.